# Codeigniter routes with question mark & regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, routes

Can anyone suggest a regular expression for this route in codeigniter

```
?config=/flash/flash_output/133/location.htm
```

I'd need a route to reroute to a controller/function called redirect/all

Any ideas of the reg expression needed to 'catch' the URL above

Comment: Okay, a few things:
1. That's not a full URL.
2. Do you just want to match the above text? What's the general format? More examples would be beneficial in constructing a reliable regex.
3. Or do you want to extract or replace any particular piece of data from the above? If so, post examples of what you're trying to do, e.g. I have x(y), and I want to convert it into x->y.

Basically, more information, please!

Comment: You should url-encode that if it's supposed to be an url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:
`\?config=\/flash\/flash_output\/133\/location.htm`
?

You don't mention if there is a class of queries you want to catch, or just this one in particular.

Dave.